# How to soft delete data in keystonejs?

Tags: keystonejs

I've created project with keystonejs (version 5) and  database is MongoDB. I need createdAt, updatedAt and deletedAt fields with timestamp in every schema. for create and update date timestamp keystonejs has provided plugin (https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/list-plugins/at-tracking) but how can I track of deleted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead of delete it,  create a `active` field and use an Update mutation to change it to false when "deleted" and have also a inactivatedAt field modified with a hook